# Laravel Plucking 5.4 error variable undefined

Tags: php, laravel, database, laravel-5, pluck

[image]Error churchdetails is not defined:

This is the pastorController

```
public function index()
{
    $pastors = Pastor::all();
    $churchdetails = Church::all()->pluck('church_name','church_address');
    return view('addpastor')->withpastors($pastors)->withchurchdetails($churchdetails);
}   

public function create()
{
   return view('addpastor');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    //validation input
    $this->validate($request, [
        'pastor_name' => 'required|max:100',
    ]);

    $pastors = New Pastor;
    $pastors->pastor_name = $request->pastor_name;

    $pastors->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

This is the view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Add Church</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'pastor.store']) !!}
                        {!!  Form::label('churches_id', 'Church Details:', null, array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) !!}

                        {!!  Form::select('churches_id', $churchdetails, null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'style' => 'height:34px', 'required' => ''))!!}


                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('pastor_name', 'Pastor Name:') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('pastor_name', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '', 'maxlength' => '100')) !!}


                    {!! Form::submit('Save Church', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'style' => 'margin-top: 20px')) !!}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

This is the route

```
Route::resource('pastor', 'pastorController');
Route::get('pastordetails', 'pastorController@index');
```

the churchdetails variable is not defined. What did I miss do to? Pls help

and I have already created the relationship between church and pastor

```
public function churches()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Church');
}

public function pastors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pastor');
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: Is the blade file you've provided `addpastor` or `adddelegate`? I can't see any use of `$churchname` anyway...

Comment: it's for the addpastor but the addpastor and adddelegate has the same error

Comment: The error you've posted says `churchname`. There isn't any use of `churchname` anywhere inside the view you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

In your statement `$churchdetails = Church::all();` in your index function, you have a semi-colon there. Is that just a typo? Also you might need to recheck your the relationship(s) you have defined. In your churches function, you're saying that a Church belongs to many churches instead of a church having many pastors if I'm understanding correctly. the churches function should be something like

```
return $this->hasMany(Pastor::class)
```

if you're trying to say a Church has many pastors

and for a pastor belonging to a church it should be

```
return $this->belongsTo(Church::class)
```

Another thing, in your form are you adding a pastor to a church at a time? The reason I ask if that a lot of your field/variable names are plural but from what i can see like the '$pastors = New Pastor;' statement in your store function is adding one $pastor

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're getting this error on the create route. Your `create()` method uses the `addpastor` view, but doesn't pass in the `churchdetails` like your `index()` method does.

Because of this, your `create()` method will error out saying that the churchdetails are not defined.

Make sure your `create()` method passes in the data it needs:

```
public function create()
{
    $churchdetails = Church::pluck('church_name','church_address');

    return view('addpastor')
        ->withchurchdetails($churchdetails);
}
```

Comment: I already added this to my create function but it still doesn't work. The churchdetails variable is still undefined